# the arabic content in the cell excel is not shown correctly

Tags: microsoft-excel, cells, table-of-contents, preview, arabic

The Text is in the cell is well written and when you click on it is is correct as shown in the upper view,
On the cell itself it is not shown correctly

For an example:

```
Cell view: حمدا 
upper view : احمد
```

Which is correct in the upper view but not in the cell itself.

The question is what can I do to sort this out,
Please help!

Comment: Does [Excel direction and language - Microsoft Community](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/excel-direction-and-language/0b3913a8-872a-44bb-ba81-333fbd3aaabc) answer you question?

Comment: What version of Excel? In Excel 365 the displayed value in the cell and the formula bar are identical. Can you upload a small example of a worksheet (Dropbox, OneDrive etc.)? (Add to your comment `@harrymc` for me to be notified.)

Comment: In Excel 365, if I copy and paste the text from superuser directly to Excel, both paste exactly as displayed in superuser.  Cell view and formula bar view are identical. Excel automatically formats the cell to align right and text in the formula bar moves to the very right of the screen. Typing in english in another cell, the cell and formula bar aligns left again. I don't have any arabic language packs installed or selected. If I use LEFT(A1,1) on the arabic text, it returns the first character from the right.

Answer (score 0):

There's more to this than meets the eye. The characters are in different order in the two reported views.

Latin example? As if the "upper view" were ABCD and the "Cell view" were DABC.

That does not happen on its own. Excel does not let one enter a series of characters, then automatically keep displaying them in the formula bar as entered, but take the last character from the string and move it to the front when displaying in the cell.

Even if the characters were numerals and related characters (like currency symbols, decimal markers, grouping markers), it might do so, though I've not seen it. But these are not numerals+, so...

If of aid, the "upper view" seems to be (Google Translate) the poster's name, "Ahmed" and so seems likely to be the desired result. Seems. If of aid.

Since it seems "Ahmed" is desired, it seems unlikely an orphan currency symbol is in the string (like $u$an, for example) so even if it is standard in the language used to enter a currency symbol, then numerals, and they then display inverted, this does not seem to do that anyway, so it wouldn't apply.

So my thoughts are two:

1. The information given is inaccurate, with perhaps the two displays coming from two different cells. Or other thoughts along those lines.
2. A bug-type problem ("feature" in Excel-speak) that somehow has not been noticed before. Or has been, just not by the poster, and the millions of users where he is do not use English language help sites too much so none have noticed this question yet.

Answer (score 0):

Add space before and after the arabic word in the cell it will change as it was appearing in the formula bar (upper view).